# When I reloaded the NGINX with acontainer, I got the open() '/var/run/nginx.pid' failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx

When I reloaded the NGINX with a container,
I got the open() '/var/run/nginx.pid' failed (2: No such file or directory).

How can I fix this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix this problem

```
###　relocation　 nginx.conf
nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

[image]
[image]